# mongodb multifield sort

Tags: ruby, mongodb, sorting

I wonder how to do multifield sorting in mongodb driver of ruby

[Example of sorting from official site](http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/file.TUTORIAL.html#Sorting_Documents_in_a_Collection) where we can find the following example:

```
# Sort in ascending order by :i
coll.find.sort(:i)

# Sort in descending order by :i
coll.find.sort(:i => :desc)
```

According to these examples I tired to do something like this

```
coll.find.sort(:i,:j)
```

and this is didn't work

Do you know the right way to do multifield sorting in ruby driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after a short investigation the answer was found

we can use either

```
hash_as_sort_parameters({:field1 => :asc, "field2" => :desc})
```

or

```
array_as_sort_parameters([["field1", :asc], ["field2", :desc]])
```

the first way with hash doesn't work for me for some reason, but the second is completely ok

Answer (score 1):

The sorting method can either take a key for single field sorting, or an array of **[key, direction] pairs** for multiple field sorting. Here's what yours would look like :

```
coll.find.sort(["score", 1], ["created_at", 1])
```

Comment: You can also use :ascending and :descending, not sure about the integer but since you wrote it I guess that works too. The docs are actually a little confusing on this, I've tried sort(:i => :desc) but I got an error saying I need to use the array syntax.

Comment: As of ruby 1.9.3p194 and mongo 1.9.0, this fails with a strange error. I needed to pass the sort method an array of arrays, that is: coll.find.sort([["score",1],["created_at"],1]]).